# Why do I see zero data usage in my network settings?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I am trying to understand why my Internet connection is slow. As a first step, I went to Settings -> Network and Internet -> Data usage. Strangely, I see 0 MB in both wifi and Ethernet 2:

[image]

This does not make sense, since I am connected to the internet  (via Ethernet). Why do I see zeros?

Comment: The above will only be true if using an unregistered adapter of some kind - e.g. cellular adapter that looks like wireless.

Comment: @John I have an original Dell laptop, Is it possible that the adapter that comes with the laptop is unregistered?

Comment: If the adapter and the machine are all Dell then it should show up. Maybe try the first initial repair for Windows. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator, and run  DISM.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and then follow this with  SFC  /SCANNOW  Restart when done and test the adapter results.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem the fix is simple go to **start---settings---network&inthernet---status** all the way down there is network reset click it and restart your computer

warning you might have some previous settings applied, when you will reset your network all previous settings will set to default.